# How to get an appropriate C++ for compiling CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw

I use MinGW64+msys on Winodws7 64bit

Now I’m trying to build CMAKE but I can’t.

When I typed `./configure` soon an error happened. .

```
---------------------------------------------
CMake 3.2.3, Copyright 2000-2015 Kitware, Inc.
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate C++ compiler on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable CXX.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.
```

I also find error messages in Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log like bellow.

[First Message in the log file]

```
In file included from c:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/iosfwd:40:0,^M
                 from c:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/ios:38,^M
                 from c:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/ostream:38,^M
                 from c:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/iostream:39,^M
                 from cmake_bootstrap_4468_test.cxx:3:^M
c:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/postypes.h:40:35: fatal error: cw
char: No such file or directory^M
compilation terminated.^M
```

[Second Message in the log file]

```
cmake_bootstrap_4468_test.cxx:5:23: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or dir
ectory^M
compilation terminated.^M
Test failed to compile
```

They said `cwchar` and `iostream.h` doesn't exist, although I have them and set their path to environmental variable.

The first massage said my C++ compiler isn’t appropriate. I installed it by `mingw-get.exe`.

Does anyone know, how can I get appropriate C++ compiler?

Comment: Why you try to build it yourself? Installers/prebuilt binaries miss something?

Comment: Just learning, thanks.

Comment: Your errors are rather weird. There's no `iostream.h` because STL headers are without extension. Why was your C compiler found but not C++? How can it be something so fundamental like `cwchar` is missing? It seems you screwed up your MinGW installation.

Comment: I extracted `x86_64-5.3.0-release-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0.7z` into `C:\MinGW64` and installed `mingw-get.exe` into `C:\MinGW64` too. Then I selected `mingw32-base` and `msys-base` and `mingw32-gcc-g++` from `Basic Setup`. What’s wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed two compilers. I recommend: delete your old one and install [msys2+mingw64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30071634/2546626).

Comment: I solved this by another way .I used `MSYS-20111123.zip` from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/External%20binary%20packages%20%28Win64%20hosted%29/MSYS%20%2832-bit%29/
 and `x86_64-5.3.0-release-win32-seh-rt_v4-rev0.7z` from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/5.3.0/threads-win32/seh/
Now I have a new problem and will ask in another thread. Thanks anyway.